# Can not select rows where column values are empty string in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a column which has varchars like "172.54". I am trying to insert into another table where this columns datatype is float. I am getting error saying can not convert datatype varchar to float. So I do

```
SELECT * 
FROM TBL 
WHERE ISNUMERIC(COLNAME) <> 1
```

And I get no results. But casting is not working. So I look and I have empty strings in that column. So I try to

```
SELECT * 
FROM TBL 
WHERE COLNAME = ''
```

And also every other different amount of spaces.

I ultimately just want to convert the empty strings to null

Also `len(colname) = 1`

Comment: try `ltrim(rtrim(COLNAME))=''`

Comment: Did that still nothing

Comment: It would help if you update your question with the table schema and some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @test varchar(10) = ' ' -- any number of spaces is equivalent to ''
select try_convert( float, @test ) as floatval -- '' gives you 0
select case when @test = '' then NULL else try_convert( float, @test ) end as floatval -- value '' returns NULL instead of 0
```

Comment: Right but the problem is i can not select it to convert.

Comment: I thought you were selecting all the rows from the table; the blank spaces would be mixed in. Code above should solve that by converting numbers that can be converted, while making other values NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you column has some characters other than `numeric` data. Also `empty string` will be converted to `zero` it will not throw error.

To filter `Numeric` data use

```
COLNAME not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Try something like this

```
insert into tablename (col1,col2)
SELECT col1,col2 FROM TBL
COLNAME not like '%[^0-9]%'
```